# Query firestore based on array contains and orderby

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing some data in `firestore` and it looks as follows:

[image]

What I have is a collection called Items, inside of it I have many documents that each has its own ID and inside each document there are multiple fields.

One of the fields is UserID which shows which user holds the item.

Now, I had like to query `firestore` in a way that will return me all of the items where their popularity is greater than 3.5 and when my own ID is not one of the ID's shown in the UserID array.

Is there any option to do so?

Currently im using the following:

```
db.collection( "Items" ).orderBy( "Popularity", Query.Direction.DESCENDING ).whereGreaterThan( "Popularity", "3.5" ).limit( 50).get()
```

But it also returns results where my ID appears in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not offer any queries that check for the non-existence of data in the document.  Firestore indexes only work based on the presence of data - you can't efficiently index things that don't exist.  So, the part of your requirements that says "when my own ID is not one of the ID's shown in the UserID array" is not possible.  You can instead write code in the client app to filter out the documents where the current user's UID is missing.